# SQL composite primary key duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

*[vb.net, sql server 2008 r2, procedure]*

**I am having problems with my composite primary key. I have a table:**

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  column1 NUMERIC,
  column2 NUMERIC,
  PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2)
);

1-1
1-2
1-2
2-1
2-2
2-3
3-1
...
```

But sometimes the user got the error... "Cannot insert duplicate key".

**Trying to find a reason for it... I am doing the insert in the following way:**

In my vb.net application, first I am selecting the last number of column1. And after it, I add +1.

**Example:**

```
Dim column2 As Integer = 206

// Here I get the last number of column1, and then I add + 1
Dim column1 As Integer = DALExample.GetLastNumber(column2)

// Here I insert the next row
DALExample.Insert(column1 + 1, column2)
```

**I have thousands and thousands of users, maybe 2  more users are doing it at the same time and then they have got the error.**

**What I am thinking to do to solve this problem:**

I will not select the last value of column1 in my web application. I will do it directly in my procedure. Example:

```
INSERT INTO example
    (column1, 
     column2)
SELECT 
    ISNULL(MAX(column1), 0) + 1 FROM example WHERE column2 = 206, 
    206
```

**In this way, there is some possibility of doubling? (I was looking for auto-increment, but it is impossible in composite primary key) Is there any better way to do it?**

Thanks!

Comment: Why not using the sequences/ autoincremental numbers.?

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd you can only have a single identity column on a table

Comment: is this a link table that relates to other tables? please provide some more context as to how the data in this table relates to other tables or your code.

Comment: @Tanner column1 is not a link to other table, but column2 is a link to a table.

Comment: @guinatal and are either of them unique? is the relationship one-many and in what direction. Pease add this information to the question as it will help people to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still get the duplicate key error with the Statement given. When two users want to insert at the same time, they execute the insert's select query at the same time and get the same value back.

Here are some ways to deal with this:

- Lock the table. Select the max id. Insert data. Unlock the table.
- Insert. If this fails, try again (and again and again till it works).
- Does column1 have a *meaning*? If so, how can two users want to insert a record with the same meaning? If not, why not use a sequence to get a value?

Comment: Are you 100% sure about this? Essentially there are two SQL statements now: a read (for the max number) and a write (the insert). Will the read acquire a shared lock on the table and, depending on the transaction isolation level, will it be able to read an insert from another transaction (in which case your answer is correct depending on the chosen isolation level)? Or will the read be seen as part of the insert and acquire an exclusive lock in which case nothing goes wrong?

Comment: @Ronald Wildenberg: Only 99% sure. An insert doesn't lock the table if not explicitely commanded to do so. I've just looked it up; it seems using the insert statement with `WITH(TABLOCK)` does.

Comment: Just to let you know. I am doing the insert and select in the same time (I am not locking the table) and I never more had the problem. Maybe the users are not inserting data EXACTLY in the same time. Maybe the milliseconds are different and the sql server can separate it.